# Depends: openjdk-7-jre-headless (= 7u75-2.5.4-1~deb7u1) but it is not going to be installed

Tags: apt

i want to install Openjdk but i get this error :

```
root@debian~# apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openjdk-7-jdk : Depends: openjdk-7-jre (= 7u75-2.5.4-1~deb7u1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

i try this commands by my issue still not solved :

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

how should i fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
sudo apt-get install tzdata=2014j-0wheezy1
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```